# Is the Boxcar Function a Wavelet?

Tags: terminology, fourier-transform, wavelets

Perhaps the simplest wavelet I've found, in my cursory glance over the field, is the Haar wavelet:
$$\psi (t) = \operatorname{sgn}\left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right)\, \Theta(t)\, \Theta(1 - t),$$
with $\operatorname{sgn}$ the sign function, and $\Theta$ the Heaviside step function.

That function seems more complicated than a the simpler boxcar one, though:
$$\psi (t) = \Theta\left(t + \frac{1}{2}\right)\, \Theta\left(\frac{1}{2} - t\right).$$

Is this considered a wavelet? If so, what's it's name? If not, why not? Part of why I ask is because Wikipedia describes the [Shannon wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_wavelet) as the Fourier dual of the Haar wavelet, when it seems like the boxcar wavelet is more accurately described as its dual.

Comment: Isn't the second function identically $0$ except at $t = 1/2$, where $\psi(t) = 0 \text{ or } 1 \text{ or } 1/4$ (depending on the definition of $\Theta(t)$)?

Comment: Thanks! Good catch on that typo.

Comment: it's rather difficult for nonnegative functions to be orthogonal. Thus it seems that a basic requirement for wavelets is violated. (But I am not an expert.)

Comment: As long as the intervals on which the boxars are non-zero do not overlap, they are orthogonal with respect to any $L^p$ metric.